# While upgrading packages, I'm getting err in samba-libs on my ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, samba

I'm trying to upgrading my packages in ubuntu 16.04. But its showing error in samba libs, saying hash mismatch. Even I tried with `--try-fix-missing` but that didn't help.

[image]

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-70 linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-70-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-signed-generic
  linux-signed-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libsmbclient libwbclient0 python-samba samba samba-common samba-common-bin
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules smbclient
10 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,163 kB/8,593 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 samba-libs amd64 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7 [5,163 kB]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 samba-libs amd64 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7                                   
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 samba-libs amd64 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7 [5,163 kB]                        
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 samba-libs amd64 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7                                   
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 10.3 MB in 49s (208 kB/s)                                                                                                                    
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/samba-libs_4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it work for use:

Remove all the content of `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory:

```
sudo apt clean 
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove
```

And then `upgrade` without any issues:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```